# Warning -- there's a number but no series in

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am getting this warning in the bibliography.

```
BibTeX> Warning -- there's a number but no series in "AAK04"
```

I don't have series information on this particular conference proceedings but can't get rid of the warning.

This is the particular entry -

```
@CONFERENCE{AAK04,
  author =       {Agarwal, R. and Kornhauser, A.A.},
  title =        {Energy Balance for a Direct Carbon Molten Carbonate Fuel Cell},
  booktitle =    {ASME Heat Transfer / Fluids Engineering Summer Conference},
  address =      {Charlotte},
  number =       {HT-FED2004-56887},
  year =         {2004},
  series =   {}
  }
```

And this is the entry in the main document using the `database.bib` file.

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{database}
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here or how to correct it?

I am using TeXnicCenter and MikTeX package.

UPDATE 7/6/14

As per @egreg recommendation which made sense, I've changed the entry in .bib file to this:

```
@CONFERENCE{AAK04,
  author =       {Agarwal, R. and Kornhauser, A.A.},
  title =        {Energy Balance for a Direct Carbon Molten Carbonate Fuel Cell},
  booktitle =    {ASME Heat Transfer / Fluids Engineering Summer Conference},
  volume =       {3},
  address =      {Charlotte},
  note =         {Paper no. HT-FED2004-56887},
  year =         {2004}
  }
```

My output is like this:

> R. Agarwal and A.A. Kornhauser. Energy balance for a direct carbon molten carbonate
>   fuel cell. In ASME Heat Transfer / Fluids Engineering Summer Conference,
>   volume 3, Charlotte, 2004. Paper no. HT-FED2004-56887.

Also, the original issue in this post was regarding the warning. The warning is because number and series go together for "conference" or "inproceedings" but not for "journal" where volume and number go together. This is the inference I could draw in case somebody encounters this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, typically we do not put a thank or sign the posts (there is a box with your info)

Comment: A warning is only a warning. It should help you, not to stop you.

Comment: As series is only optional for `@conference`, don't write it in the entry.

Comment: `number` refers to a series of books (for instance, Academic Press' “Pure and Applied Mathematics”) or the issue number of a journal's volume. Probably `HT-FED2004-56887` should go in a `note` field, with an explanation of its meaning; in the ASME site it is presented as “Paper number” and is part of the DOI, which is `doi:10.1115/HT-FED2004-56887`

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I agree but this is not the only entry that gives me the warning. There are more.

Comment: @Bernard Excluding the series entry does not do a thing. The warning remains. Originally, I didn't had the series entry but included to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @user46001 Can you report on progress?

Comment: @egreg I think you are correct in pointing out that "number" field in bibtex cannot be filled with "Paper Number". Many journals have got volume and number that go together even if there is no series. So I have removed the entry "number" and added the note field. There's no warning now but what I am seeing now is the bib entry having a period at the end of the year followed by the "note" and then another period which kind of looks odd. Please see update above.

Comment: Removing the period would require changing `plainnat.bst`

Comment: @egreg I understand what you are recommending. I looked at the plainnat.bst file and realized that some section of the code has to be modified to be able to change from period to comma.  I have checked other people citing this reference and realized the paper number or doi no. not being used.  I might simply remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `number` refers to a series of books (for instance, Academic Press' “Pure and Applied Mathematics”) or the issue number of a journal's volume. Probably `HT-FED2004-56887` should go in a `note` field, with an explanation of its meaning; in the ASME site it is presented as “Paper number” and is part of the DOI, which is `doi:10.1115/HT-FED2004-56887`.

Unfortunately the `plainnat` style doesn't support a `doi` field. You can do

```
@inproceedings{AAK04,
  author =       {Agarwal, R. and Kornhauser, A.A.},
  title =        {Energy Balance for a Direct Carbon Molten Carbonate Fuel Cell},
  booktitle =    {ASME Heat Transfer / Fluids Engineering Summer Conference},
  volume =       {3},
  address =      {Charlotte},
  note =         {Paper no. HT-FED2004-56887},
  year =         {2004}
  }
```

and, if you don't want the `note` field to appear, just change `note` into `OPTnote` or any other inexistent field name.

The `conference` type is the same as `inproceedings`, I just prefer the latter.